# What assumptions are needed to prove $\int_{h(\alpha)}^{h(\cdot)}g=\int_{\alpha}^{(\cdot)}(g\circ h )\cdot h'$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

I tried to prove the following statement:

> $\displaystyle\int_{h(\alpha)}^{h(\cdot)}g=\int_{\alpha}^{(\cdot)}(g\circ h )\cdot h'$

I am still new to functions involving integrals, so I was hoping I could receive a thumbs-up / thumbs-down regarding the proof. **It is not clear to me what assumptions I need to prove this**...for my proof, I just assumed that $g$ was continuous and that $(g\circ h)\cdot h'$ was continuous (maybe I can get away with fewer assumptions?)

---

First, suppose $f$ is a continuous function. Then by the *First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus* (FFTC), the following function $F_{\alpha}(\cdot)=\int_{\alpha}^{(\cdot)}f$ is an antiderivative of $f$ because $F_{\alpha}'(\cdot)=f(\cdot)$

Now, suppose $f(\cdot)=\left[g\circ h (\cdot)\right]\cdot h'(\cdot)$, where $g$ is a continuous function. By applying the *Chain Rule* and the FFTC, we see that the following function $G_{\alpha}(\cdot)$ must also be an antiderivative of $f$: $G_{\alpha}(\cdot)=\int_{\alpha}^{h(\cdot)}g$.

The above two paragraphs show that $F_{\alpha}'(\cdot)=G_{\alpha}'(\cdot)$, which, by the *Mean Value Theorem*, implies that $G_{\alpha}(\cdot)=F_{\alpha}(\cdot)+c$, where $c$ is some constant. Letting $x=\alpha$, and noting that $\int_{\alpha}^{\alpha}f=0$ we can solve for $c$ the following way:

$$G_{\alpha}(\alpha)=F_{\alpha}(\alpha)+c \implies G_{\alpha}(\alpha)=c$$

We can therefore rewrite the above expression as:

$$G_{\alpha}(\cdot)=F_{\alpha}(\cdot)+G_{\alpha}(\alpha)\iff \int_{\alpha}^{h(\cdot)}g=\int_{\alpha}^{(\cdot)}f+\int_{\alpha}^{h(\alpha)}g \quad (\dagger_1)$$

$(\dagger_1)$ can be rearranged as:

$$\int_{\alpha}^{h(\cdot)}g-\int_{\alpha}^{h(\alpha)}g=\int_{\alpha}^{(\cdot)}f$$

We can now apply some useful rules of integration, which let us claim:

1. $-\int_{\alpha}^{h(\alpha)}g=\int_{h(\alpha)}^{\alpha}g$
2. $\int^{h(\cdot)}_{\alpha}g+\int_{h(\alpha)}^{\alpha}g=\int_{h(\alpha)}^{h(\cdot)}g$

As such, we conclude that:

$$\int_{h(\alpha)}^{h(\cdot)}g=\int_{\alpha}^{(\cdot)}f = \int_{\alpha}^{(\cdot)} \left[g \circ h\right]\cdot h'$$

---

Comment: It is not completely clear whether your question is: "Is my proof correct with the assumptions I chose?" or "What are the weakest (or: weaker?) assumptions under which this equality holds?"

Comment: @AnneBauval The question is two-fold. 1) Is this an appropriate proof given my assumptions? 2) Are there weaker assumptions that can be made for this to be true

Comment: Better focus on one question. I think the second question deserves a separate post. (Or may be it is a duplicate.)

Comment: I think your proof is fine until $G_{\alpha}(\alpha)=F_{\alpha}(\alpha)+c$ but could be shortened after that, if you had chosen to define $G_{\alpha}(\cdot)=\int_{h(\alpha)}^{h(\cdot)}g$ instead of $G_{\alpha}(\cdot)=\int_{\alpha}^{h(\cdot)}g.$ This way, you would immediately have $G_\alpha(\alpha)=0$ (like $F_\alpha(\alpha)=0$) hence $c=0.$

Comment: Minimum Weaker Criteria : " $g$ is Continuous ++ $h$ is Differentiable " : [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Proof ] + [ https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/~ashenk/Section6_8.pdf ]